# Hadoop distcp does not skip CRC checks

Tags: hadoop, sftp, amazon-emr, distcp

I have an issue with skipping CRC checks between source and target paths running distcp.
I copy and decrypt files on demand and their checksum is different, that is expected.

My command looks like following:

`hadoop distcp -skipcrccheck -update -direct sftp://path s3a://path`

When hadoop distcp starts, it prints configs and there is skipCRC=true

But job fails with error:

- Mismatch in length of source:sftp://path (95066273) and target:s3a://path/.distcp.tmp.attempt_1675828993400_0012_m_000001_1 (95065888)

hadoop version - **Hadoop 3.2.1-amzn-5**

Have anyone had a luck with skipping CRC checks?

I updated EMR to 6.9.0 with **hadoop 3.3.3**
what was supposed to help based on this [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-17932). but it didn't and job still fails on CRC validation.